# Is it a good idea to call a dll made of VC++6.0 from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-c++-6

I have to deal with one ancient software module which only support its API being called from VC++6.0.

If I add an indirection layer, that is, wrapping the module in a dynamic library written with VC++6.0 and transferring API to the underlying module. The dll will be called from a VC++ tool chain provided in Visual Studio 2015.

My question is:

1. Is this doable in principle?
2. Are there any pitfalls one might want to may attention?
3. Can it be done in a better way?

Update: I guess that the C ABI is stable through different windows versions as well as corresponding supported VS version. If the dll is made with pure C, this might be done without too much trouble.

Comment: Yes, this is doable. Yes, you basically need a C-style interface, and to avoid passing resource ownership across module boundaries (e.g. allocate memory in the DLL to be freed in the client EXE, unless you use OS-provided functions like `GlobalAlloc` on both ends). The implementation doesn't have to be pure C, just the interface.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two issues preventing portability between versions/vendors: C++ object/class layout and the C/C++ memory allocators.

To avoid the first issue you should design the visible API as a set of C functions (like most of the Win32 API).

The memory issue can be solved by switching from `new`/`malloc` to one of the native Windows functions like `LocalAlloc`, `HeapAlloc` or `CoTaskMemAlloc`. Assuming your old .dll is not statically linked it would theoretically be possible to force newer code to use the `malloc` in msvcrt.dll but it makes your build setup a bit fragile and it goes against current best practices.

Another alternative is for the middleman .dll to implement everything as a COM object:

```
EXTERN_C HRESULT WINAPI CreateMyObject(IMyObject**ppv) ...
```

Comment: Do you mind giving a hint on how to force the od dll to use LocalAlloc, HeapAlloc, CoTaskNewAlloc, etc instead of its default allocator?

Comment: The only important rule is that your application cannot call `free`/`delete` on memory it got from the .dll. If the .dll is not statically linked then the middleman .dll (if compiled with vc6) can call `free` on your behalf. You can in theory IAT hook the .dlls calls to `malloc`/`free` and use `LocalAlloc` etc instead but I would avoid that if possible.